# HTTPError: HTTP Error 503: Service Unavailable

Tags: jupyter-notebook, pytorch, yolov5

I am trying to use YOLOv5 Ultralytics but this error is coming.I opened Inspect and this is what is appearing

[This is Inspect window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QL7G9.png)
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQhjE.png)

CODE-

```py
!pip install torch torchvision torchaudio
!git clone https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5
!cd yolov5 & pip install -r requirements.txt

import torch
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import cv2

model = torch.hub.load('ultralytics/yolov5', 'yolov5s')
```

This is my code

And error appears after I execute `torch.hub.load` in a single cell of jupyter notebook

Comment: Hy, welcome to Stack Overflow, please [don't upload text, table or error message as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557). 
Edit your question to contain all the information in text form - consider to use the editor's formatting options. 
Also see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)